# How to work with dataframe in which data for each column starts from different dates?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with historical monthly stock prices (starting from 1980) reported under each column. However, price history for each (50 in total) of them starts at different date and I need to run analysis since inception, i.e. since the beginning of price history for each stock? 
How is that possible, do I need to split original dataframe into multiple dataframes based on date from which stock price is available or there is other way around?
Many thanks in advance

```
A   B   C
1980-01 0.02    na  na
1980-02 0.03    na  na
1980-03 0.01    0.0231  na
1980-04 0.0231  0.011   na
1980-05 0.011   0.0005  na
1980-06 0.0005  0.001   0.0032
1980-07 0.001   0.005   0.004
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of analysis you need to apply. But you may get the first non-NA value's index for each column quite easily:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)
```

You may then start with the given index of each column.